# logstash create multiple json files in a folder for output

Tags: json, logstash

I want to use logstash to read data from a table in a database and create a separate json file for each entry within the table...

I see that logstash already interprets the data in json, because when I output to an existing json object, the data is already in json object format.

Is it possible to create the json documents separately and store them in one folder in the output block of logstash?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible, however you will have to have a field in your event that you use as (part) filename. Here is my Config:

(Output only):

```
output { 
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    file {
         path => "/home/artur/tmp/logstash/out/%{hello}.log"
    }

}
```

the filename will be whatever is in the field %{hello} which comes from my event. Logstash automatically fills it in.

For these two events:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
a
{
       "message" => "a",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-01T09:28:54.206Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "test",
        [1] "test2",
        [2] "test3",
        [3] "test4"
    ],
         "hello" => "world",
    "mynewField" => "test4"
}
b
{
       "message" => "b",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-01T09:28:59.454Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "test",
        [1] "test2",
        [2] "test3",
        [3] "test4"
    ],
         "hello" => "world2",
    "mynewField" => "test4"
}
```

It creates 2 files:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/logstash/out$ ls
world2.log  world.log
```

I hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: thanks arthur, does the filename get configured in the _filter_ part of the config file?

Comment: @Kazi the filename (in output) depends on your event. your event will have to have some field that you can use to populate the filename. You can either use whatever is in your event already, or you can use the mutate filter to create a filename field to use. If you want different filenames, you will have to find a way to create unique filenames (or e.g. use the pkey field of the database event you receive, since that one MUST be unique)